# Eclipse doesn't resolve object type in php array

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

I came from Java world and try the same "easy" things in Php.

I have a immutable dummy data object:

```
class BugTimeData {

    private $bugid = "";
    private $startDate = "";
    private $resolvedDate = "";
    private $status = "";
    private $weekends = ""; 

    function __construct($bugid, $startDate, $resolvedDate, $status) {
        $this->bugid = $bugid;
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
        $this->resolvedDate = $resolvedDate;
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    function getBugId() {
        return $this->bugid;
    }

    function getStartDate() {
        return $this->startDate;
    }

    function getResolvedDate() {
        return $this->resolvedDate;     
    }

    function getStatus() {
        return $this->status;
    }

    function getWeekendsBetween() {
        return $this->weekends;
    }
}
```

A add a object from this class into an array:

```
$data= new BugTimeData($a, $b, $c, $d);
array_push($content, $data);
```

I want to iterate over this array, read out objects and access their methods:

```
foreach($time_prio_bug_content as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value->getStatus());
}
```

This works! But my IDE (Eclipse) does not really know that $value is from type `BugTimeData`. So I cannot access public methods in a easy way.

**Question:**
How to cast $value to a object from type `BugTimeData`?

In Java this is really easy (because I do not need a cast because I can define the type of the objects when creating an array) and straight forward. So I wonder why this is not possible in Php?

Comment: `$value` is already an object.

Comment: @CORRUPT Sure, but not from type BugTimeData.

Comment: PHP does not support what you are trying to do natively.  The IDE that I use, PhpStorm, allows you to use annotations to declare the type (class or primitive) of any variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a problem of your IDE, not of PHP. If you add the appropriate annotation type hints, any decent IDE will pick up on it. For instance, define that the array contains objects of a certain type:

```
/** @var BugTimeData[] $array */
$array = array();
```

If the data comes from a function or method, add an appropriate `@return` documentation tag to the method's signature. Worst case, mark the variable inside the loop:

```
foreach($time_prio_bug_content as $key => $value) {
    /** @var BugTimeData $value */
    var_dump($value->getStatus());
}
```

Comment: Okay...seems to work with Eclipse. Nice! I do not really understand why casts to object, int, binary etc. are possible when PHP is a dynamically typed language at all. However...problem is solved!

Comment: @sk2 "Dynamically typed" doesn't mean "type free". PHP is just as typed as Java is, but types are inferred by context without needing to be declared explicitly everywhere (of course `$foo = 'bar'` is a string, no need to declare it) and are converted implicitly as needed based on the operation (of course `$foo + $bar` uses two integers, no need to convert them explicitly). The only difference really is that you do not need to redundantly type `String string = 'string'` or `string.toNumber()`.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to Annotation I believe you can [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) as such:

```
var $value = new BugTimeData; // this tells the IDE which type the variable will hold from here on
foreach($time_prio_bug_content as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value->getStatus());
}
```

or implement a class method for the cast with type hinting the argument and return object (see [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php#103729))

Comment: type hints are for arguments, not for return values. It may be added in php 6 - it's in RFC form here: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/returntypehint2

Comment: @BobGregor You are completely missing the point. My code (and the links) do not mean to type hint function return values. Instead, by explicitly declaring the variable `$value` before it is used. I am helping the IDE understand what it's type is going to be in the following code.

Comment: Ah! Now I see your point - you may want to add a comment in your code sample to indicate that the $value element is a temporary hint for the IDE. I've done that hack in the past with IDE's.

Answer (score -2):

You can't. Because PHP is practically typeless, and when reading code there's no way to know what type a certain variable is. It is only possible during runtime.